# Automatically call httpservice.send

Tags: xml, apache-flex, flex3, httpservice

I have an application that displays the data from 3 xml files (auto generated from SQL table) using httpservices to get them.
The first xml file is small and contains around 30 items, the second and thrid contain around 200-300 items each.
The first dataset loads quickly and is invoked on creationComplete. The second and third are called from click events and take quite a few seconds to load. A user of the application will take at least 2-3 minutes reading the data from the first dataset so is there a way I can have the httpservice.send for the second and third xml files called automatically, straight after the first file has finished loading to be able to show the first dataset immediateley and get rid of the waiting times between dataset views. An answer doesnt need to be specific, just a point in the right direction would be great.

All answers greatly appreciated

Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Use AMF instead](http://www.jamesward.com/2009/06/17/blazing-fast-data-transfer-in-flex/).  It's much faster than XML.

Answer (score 0):

yeah, just run the httpService.send() method on 2&3 as part of the result event from 1